# Nginx handling a context path problem using referrer

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, referrer

I am new to nginx and probably I do not know how to ask this question. I am proxy passing https://nginx.org/ with the following configuration.

```
events {
}

http {

    include mime.types;

    server {
        listen 80;

        location /nginx-test/ {
            proxy_pass https://nginx.org/;
        }
    }
}
```

When I request http://my-load-balancer-ip/nginx-test I mainly get most of the resources except favicon.ico, nginx.png vs.

Because the path of these resources are :

```
<img src="/nginx.png" alt="nginx">
```

So they are being requested as

```
http://my-load-balancer-ip/nginx.png -> 404
```

However, I am expecting these request as

```
http://my-load-balancer-ip/nginx-test/nginx.png
```

Is there a way to accomplish this kind of behavior in Nginx like if the referer is http://my-load-balancer-ip/nginx-test/ then handle these requests gracefully.